# MVC Dropdownlist only returns item's id, not item's name

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have created a dropdownlist that is connected to the other table which is the ResidentRegisters, however, when I select from the dropdownlist then click Create, the only value that is displayed at the table is the ID of the resident, not the full name of the resident.

Here is my Controller

```
    // GET: Blotterreports/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ResidentViewModels models = new ResidentViewModels();
        models.ResidentList = new SelectList(db.ResidentRegisters, "ID", "FullName");

        return View(models);
    }

    // POST: Blotterreports/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "incidents, ResidentList ")] ResidentViewModels inc_report)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            inc_report.ResidentList = new SelectList(db.ResidentRegisters, "ID", "FullName", 1);

            db.Blotterreports.Add(inc_report.incidents);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        inc_report.ResidentList = new SelectList(db.ResidentRegisters, "ID", "FullName", 1) ;

        return View(inc_report); 
    }
```

**My Model**

```
public class Blotterreports
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Blotter Number") Required]
    public int Blotternumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Resident ID") ]


    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName

    { get ; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ResidentRegister> Resident { get; set; }

}

 public class ResidentRegister
    {

    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Resident Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return  ID + ".)" + ResidentFirstName + " " + ResidentMiddleName + " " + ResidentLastName; }
        set { }
    }

    [Display(Name = "First Name") Required]
    public string ResidentFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Middle Name") Required]
    public string ResidentMiddleName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name") Required]
    public string ResidentLastName { get; set; }
```

**My View Model**

```
  public class ResidentViewModels
    {
        public ResidentRegister fullname { get; set; }

        public Blotterreports incidents { get; set; }

        public Clearances documents { get; set; }

        public SelectList ResidentList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My View**

Create new record

```
   <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.incidents.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.incidents.FullName, Model.ResidentList, "Please select a resident", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.incidents.ResidentFirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

The value that should be returned and displayed at the table should be the resident's full name.

Comment: how about you store your select list in a viewbag like this

Comment: ViewBag.mySelectList

Comment: and use it like this

Comment: @Html.DropDown("mySelectList",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.mySelectList))